# Bug: RavenDb sql replication for npgsql cannot replication json type

Tags: postgresql, ravendb, npgsql

I added a RavenDb SQL replication for using npgsql, but there is a problem:

Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42804: column "data" is of type json but expression is of type text at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.DoReadMessage(DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean isPrependedMessage)

RavenDb sql replication scripts is: [RavenDb Sql Replication for npgsql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBUg0.png)

And postgre sql table is: [Table columns in postgre sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqc1p.png)

I removed the quotes, escaped and otherwise, this makes a new issue "cannot convert RavenJObject to string"

This is using ravendb sql replication, so no code for this question

Comment: The value of `data` in your `client` object is text. Remove the quotes, escaped and otherwise.

Comment: If I removed it, is makes a convert error: Cannot convert RavenJObject to string

Comment: Can you please post the code the attempts to insert the row into PostgreSQL? You probably need to specify `NpgsqlDbType.Json` on your NpgsqlParameter

Answer (score 0):

I added code to npgsql-dev branch in class "NpgCommand" and the issue has fixed, see picture:

[Source code change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCIMs.png)

But change the Npgsql 3.1.6.0 source code is not valid, I don't know why...